# SQlite database android studio in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

new in SQlite database Android studio right now I have an application that stores some data in a Table like name, phone number0 and date. and i have a Date Picker. What I want is when I pick a date it shows only the data that has a date that equals to the date I Picked from the Date Picker. I would like an answer in kotlin if possible. but even in java should do it I will convert it. thanks

```
 fun DateCount(): Int {

     val db = this.readableDatabase
     val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT $DATE_COLUMN FROM $TABLE_NAME", null) // dont know what to write here
     val count = cursor.count
     cursor.close()
     return count

 }
```

Comment: If you are looking for someone who writes the code for you, this is not the right place. Here is a link where you can learn how SQL querys work https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

> val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT $DATE_COLUMN FROM $TABLE_NAME", null) // dont know what to write here

You need a **WHERE** clause something like:-

```
 fun DateCount(pickedDate: String): Int {

     val db = this.readableDatabase
     val cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT $DATE_COLUMN FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $DATE_COLUMN = '$pickedDate'", null) // dont know what to write here
     val count = cursor.count
     cursor.close()
     return count
 }
```

- pickedDate would be the date selected from the Date Picker.
- pickedDate must be in exactly the same format as the data that is saved.
- So if the date contained time as well as date then you'd have to either change the **=** for a LIKE clause e.g. `WHERE $DATE_COLUMN LIKE '$pickedDate%'`
- or you could use the SQLite substr function e.g. `WHERE substr($DATE_COLUMN,1,length($pickedDate)) = $pickedDate`
- You should also consider utilising the 3rd parameter of rawQuery to bind pickedDate (i.e. use a **`?`** in the SQL as have the 3rd parameter as a String[] with pickedDate as the only element). This protects against SQL injection.